# The effect of pressing the button

Tags: ios, swift, button, xcode8

How can I do that would be when you click on it was getting dark and back, but so the text would always be visible.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: Use the color code of your text as the background color of button and background color of your screen as , background color of button.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava It is necessary that the button darkens when you click

Comment: Change the button's background color as superview's color on uibutton action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Button to Custom type, and customize highlighted and selected state:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the background and text colors when user taps.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `UIButton` subclass and set the background images for the different control states:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }

    private func sharedInit() {
        setBackgroundImage(UIColor.darkGrayColor().image, forState: .Normal)
        setBackgroundImage(UIColor.blackColor().image, forState: .Highlighted)
        setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    }

}

extension UIColor {

    var image: UIImage {
        return imageWithSize(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    }

    func imageWithSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)

        self.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }

}
```